# Problema na condição ao verificar se o usuário digitou "n", "N", "s" ou "S"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("--------------------") 
print("CALCULADORA DE MÉDIA")
print("--------------------")

print()

#Primeira nota
v1 = float(input("Digite a primeira nota: "))

#Segunda nota
v2 = float(input("Digite a segunda nota: "))

#Média
media = (v1 + v2) / 2

print("A nota da sua média é:", media)
print()


#Pergunta = Pergunta do Ponto Extra
pergunta = str(input("Deseja adicionar algum ponto extra? [S/N]:"));

#Verifica se o usuário quer adicionar um ponto extra na média
if pergunta == "s" or "S":

"""Erro aqui, caso eu insira "n" ou "N" na "pergunta", ele realiza esse "pontoextra"
sendo que, quando for digitado "N" ou "n", eu não quero que ele realize essa parte!"""
pontoextra = float(input("Digite o(s) ponto(s) extra(s): "));

media = media + pontoextra;
print("A sua média final é:", media);

#Verifica se o usuário não quer adicionar ponto(s) extra(s) na média
if pergunta == "n" or "N":
print("Programa encerrado!");

#Caso ele responda algo diferente de "S" ou "N", retorna um erro
else:
print("Resposta inválida!")
```

Basicamente, o que eu não estou conseguindo resolver é a variável "pontoextra".

Caso o usuário digite "N" ou "n" na variável "pergunta", eu quero que ele somente encerre o programa, e mostre na tela que o programa foi encerrado. Mas, tem um porém, aquela variável "pontoextra" está sendo utilizada mesmo se eu digitar "N" ou "n", que equivale a "não" adicionar o ponto extra.

Comment: Basicamente, o que eu não estou conseguindo resolver é a variável "pontoextra".

Comment: Caso o usuário digite "N" ou "n" na variável "pergunta", eu quero que ele somente encerre o programa, e mostre na tela que o programa foi encerrado. Mas, tem um porém, aquela variável "pontoextra" está sendo utilizada mesmo se eu digitar "N" ou "n", que equivale a "não" adicionar o ponto extra.

Comment: uma maneira facil de verificar o ´S` e `s` é pegando a entrada e transforma-lá sempre em letras minuscula, assim voce só precisa fazer uma comparação `pergunta.lower()`, desta maneira você só precisa verificar se é igual a `s` ou `n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, lembre-se que a identação é de fundamental importância no Python. Sem usar a identação correta, o seu programa não vai funcionar.

Segundo, `if pergunta == "s" or "S"` deveria ser `if pergunta == "s" or pergunta == "S"`. O mesmo vale para o `"n"`.

Terceiro, use o `elif`. Ele é o `else if` do pyhthon.

Quarto, acho que `resposta` seria um nome mais apropriado para a variável do que `pergunta`.

Assim sendo, eis como fica o seu programa:

```
print("--------------------") 
print("CALCULADORA DE MÉDIA")
print("--------------------")

print()

#Primeira nota
v1 = float(input("Digite a primeira nota: "))

#Segunda nota
v2 = float(input("Digite a segunda nota: "))

#Média
media = (v1 + v2) / 2

print("A nota da sua média é:", media)
print()


#Pergunta = Pergunta do Ponto Extra
resposta = str(input("Deseja adicionar algum ponto extra? [S/N]:"));


if resposta == "s" or resposta == "S":
    pontoextra = float(input("Digite o(s) ponto(s) extra(s): "));

    media = media + pontoextra;
    print("A sua média final é:", media);

elif resposta == "n" or resposta == "N":
    print("Programa encerrado!");

else:
    print("Resposta inválida!")
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Ajudou bastante. Estou iniciando em Python, e em uma aula que vi sobre estrutura de decisão, o cara falou que não tem diferença entre "if" e "elif", mas, agora compreendo que o "elif" é correto. Eu fico um pouco confuso com a identação do python, por ser automática haha.

Comment: @Kappa, se a minha resposta te ajudou, resolveu o problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, por favor clique no ✅ verde que tem aqui ao lado para marcar a minha resposta como aceita/correta. Caso ainda haja alguma dúvida a esclarecer, sinta-se livre para comentar. :)

Comment: @Kappa mas porque nao faz a condiçao apenas `if resposta.lower() == "s": ...` só assim escusas de comparar a maiuscula também

Answer (score 0):

Uma segunda forma séria deixa a entrada do usuário toda maiúscula ou minuscula usando o .upper() ou .lower(), se o usuário digitasse "s" e logo após o input houvesse um .upper(), o "s" ficaria "S", assim necessitando apenas de uma verificação no if.

```
print("--------------------") 
print("CALCULADORA DE MÉDIA")
print("--------------------")

print()

#Primeira nota
v1 = float(input("Digite a primeira nota: "))

#Segunda nota
v2 = float(input("Digite a segunda nota: "))

#Média
media = (v1 + v2) / 2

print("A nota da sua média é:", media)
print()


#Pergunta = Pergunta do Ponto Extra
pergunta = str(input("Deseja adicionar algum ponto extra? [S/N]:")).upper(); # isso resolveria o problema, ai só seria necessário verificar se pergunta era igual à "S" ou "N"

#Verifica se o usuário quer adicionar um ponto extra na média
if pergunta == "s" or "S":

"""Erro aqui, caso eu insira "n" ou "N" na "pergunta", ele realiza esse "pontoextra"
sendo que, quando for digitado "N" ou "n", eu não quero que ele realize essa parte!"""
pontoextra = float(input("Digite o(s) ponto(s) extra(s): "));

media = media + pontoextra;
print("A sua média final é:", media);

#Verifica se o usuário não quer adicionar ponto(s) extra(s) na média
if pergunta == "n" or "N":
print("Programa encerrado!");

#Caso ele responda algo diferente de "S" ou "N", retorna um erro
else:
print("Resposta inválida!")
```